# How to split a string based on one or more occurrences of a given character?

Tags: r, regex, string

Given the string:

```
string <- "AATTGGCGCTAG---AT-TTACG----"
```

How can I split it into strings based on the occurrence of one or more "-". For example:

```
string1 <- "AATTGGCGCTAG"
string2 <- "---"
string3 <- "AT"
string4 <- "-"
string5 <- "TTACG"
string6 <- "----"
```

I have tried:

```
strsplit(string, "[-]+")
```

However, this does not return the stings of "-"

Comment: Sorry, I thought I had ticked this. Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You may match them with

```
[^-]+|-+
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/R70znc/1). It matches

- `[^-]+` - 1+ chars other than `-`
- `|` - or
- `-+` - 1 or more `-` chars.

In R:

```
x <- "AATTGGCGCTAG---AT-TTACG----"
regmatches(x, gregexpr("[^-]+|-+", x))
```

Or

```
library(stringr)
x <- "AATTGGCGCTAG---AT-TTACG----"
str_extract_all(x, "[^-]+|-+")
```

Output

```
## => [[1]]
##    [1] "AATTGGCGCTAG" "---"   "AT"  "-"   "TTACG"   "----"
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a direct fix to your current attempt with `strsplit`:

```
string <- "AATTGGCGCTAG---AT-TTACG----"
strsplit(string, "(?<=[^-])(?=[-])|(?<=[-])(?=[^-])", perl=TRUE)[[1]]

[1] "AATTGGCGCTAG" "---"          "AT"           "-"            "TTACG"
[6] "----"
```

The idea behind the regex pattern is to split whenver one of the following two conditions be true:

- The immediate preceding character is NOT a dash, and what follows IS a dash, or
- The immediate preceding character IS a dash, and what follows is NOT a dash